# Appium codeception iOS simulator error: could not find any webviews yet refreshing/retrying

Tags: testing, mobile, ios-simulator, appium, codeception

When I try to launch safari on iPad simulator and do $I->amOnPage("http://www.amazon.com"). Safari browser is launched but is stuck at http://127.0.0.1:4723/welcome. I see in appium logs this warning "could not find any webviews yet refreshing/retrying" and then nothing happens.

I use Appium 1.4.8, OS X 10.10 Yosemite, codeception 2.1.2, XCode 6.4. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I looked up online and some said I should be running ios_webkit_proxy_launcher. I tried running that on 27753 with -c and simulator UDID -d options and retried my test. Still no change. ios proxy starts up but has no logs whatsoever. These are the desired capabilities I am using :

```
modules:
enabled:
    - WebDriver
config:
     WebDriver:
        url: 'http://www.amazon.com'
        connection_timeout: 500
        request_timeout: 500
        browser: 'safari'
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 4723
        capabilities:
          browserName: 'safari'
          platformVersion: "8.4"
          platformName: "iOS"
          deviceName: 'iPad Retina'
          connection_timeout: 500
          request_timeout: 500
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

However I can get things to work fine with PHPUnit! Dont know whats going on with codeception.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced  issue while opening webview in safari browser. I was working with iPhone device. But below pre-conditions should be same for simulator.
machine should have:

- Appium installed.
- libplist 1.10 installed.
- libusbmuxd 1.0.8 installed.
- libimobiledevice 1.1.5 installed.
- If you are running on device turn on (settings go to developer then
  UIautomator)UI automator and safari  go to advanced turn on web
  inspector.
- open terminal run following command:-

  ios_webkit_debug_proxy

  Hit enter
- open new window on terminal hit  following command:-

  ios_webkit_debug_proxy –c:27753 –d

  Don’t change port number.
- Device(in your case , simulator) should be connected to machine.

Comment: Thank you mk08. I tweaked the safari browser little bit. Codeception fails when there is no default page set to safari browser on ios with appium. I have now set default page as Google (it can be anything) and then appium is able to find the webview and it continues with the tests. Don't know if its a defect with appium or codeception or both. There is some sort of communication problem there. I didn't have to start ios proxy kit at all.

Comment: Yeah, when you invoke Safari app from iOS, driver consider it as Native View. When you navigate to some URL with driver.get("any url") then it gets WebView. There you have to explicitly switch to webview. In your case, your tweak may work . But later if you try to test hybrid app, you may face the same issue. Hence it would be useful if we check how many views available and then switch to required one.

Comment: mk08, how to switch to webview in code? Shouldn't appium be doing this if I running a test in a mobile browser?

Comment: I mentioned about webview and native view because in your case , safari app (without your tweak) was getting open with Native View . But now you have set the default page, appium would get the webview and run your tests. Switching between views while testing Hybrid Apps, is a different story and you can find n number of solutions on internet :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to enable Web Inspector of Safari on your device.

```
Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector = ON
```